# When I get output that comes in scientific number but want to get in one number

Tags: python

my input is this

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])],
                       remainder='passthrough')
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
print(x)
```

and output is this

```
[1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.70000000e+01
  6.70000000e+04]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code, just formatting.

I think your particular problem can be solved by setting precision, e.g. using np.around & setting the decimals parameter.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1e-9, 1e-2])
print(a)
# array([1.e-09, 1.e-02])
np.around(a, decimals=3)
# array([0.  , 0.01])
```